# TypeError: import_optional_dependency() got an unexpected keyword argument 'errors'

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-science

I am trying to work with Featuretools to develop an automated feature engineering workflow for the customer churn dataset. The end outcome is a function that takes in a dataset and label times for customers and builds a feature matrix that can be used to train a machine learning model.

As part of this exercise I am trying to  execute the below code for plotting a histogram and got "***TypeError: import_optional_dependency() got an unexpected keyword argument 'errors'*** ". Please help resolve this TypeError.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (10, 6)

trans.loc[trans['actual_amount_paid'] < 250, 'actual_amount_paid'].dropna().plot.hist(bins = 30)
plt.title('Distribution of Actual Amount Paid')
```

**Below is the full error I received:**

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-7e19affd5fc1> in <module>
      4 plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (10, 6)
      5 
----> 6 trans.loc[trans['actual_amount_paid'] < 250, 'actual_amount_paid'].dropna().plot.hist(bins = 30)
      7 plt.title('Distribution of Actual Amount Paid')

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\common.py in new_method(self, other)
     63                     break
     64                 if isinstance(other, cls):
---> 65                     return NotImplemented
     66 
     67         other = item_from_zerodim(other)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arraylike.py in __lt__(self, other)
     35     def __ne__(self, other):
     36         return self._cmp_method(other, operator.ne)
---> 37 
     38     @unpack_zerodim_and_defer("__lt__")
     39     def __lt__(self, other):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in _cmp_method(self, other, op)  
   4937         --------
   4938         >>> s = pd.Series(range(3))
-> 4939         >>> s.memory_usage()
   4940         152
   4941 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\array_ops.py in comparison_op(left, right, op)
    248     lvalues = ensure_wrapped_if_datetimelike(left)
    249     rvalues = ensure_wrapped_if_datetimelike(right)
--> 250 
    251     rvalues = lib.item_from_zerodim(rvalues)
    252     if isinstance(rvalues, list):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\array_ops.py in _na_arithmetic_op(left, right, op, is_cmp)
    137 
    138 def _na_arithmetic_op(left, right, op, is_cmp: bool = False):
--> 139     
    140     Return the result of evaluating op on the passed in values.
    141 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\expressions.py in <module>
     17 from pandas._typing import FuncType
     18 
---> 19 from pandas.core.computation.check import NUMEXPR_INSTALLED
     20 from pandas.core.ops import roperator
     21 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\check.py in <module>
      1 from pandas.compat._optional import import_optional_dependency
      2 
----> 3 ne = import_optional_dependency("numexpr", errors="warn")
      4 NUMEXPR_INSTALLED = ne is not None
      5 if NUMEXPR_INSTALLED:

TypeError: import_optional_dependency() got an unexpected keyword argument 'errors'
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to upgrade `pandas`:

```
pip install pandas --upgrade
```

Comment: Thanks! I have upgraded pandas and matplotlib packages and it worked.

Comment: I have got same error, updating pandas or pandas + matplotlib didn't change the error. Any idea?

Comment: Also restart jupyter server if applicable.

Comment: @intotecho the restarting was a key part to resolving my issue. Thanks.